# If grep value not found return an echo [korn shell]

Tags: linux, bash, ksh, aix

I have an issue with this script.

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
grep -w $1 list.txt > mydata.sql
cat mydata.sql
rm -f mydata.sql
else
echo "Please enter a valid input"
fi
```

What I'm trying to do is there are 3 conditions:
1- i put a valid input that is found inside the file and it gives me the output

2- **I put a wrong input that can't be found inside the file and give me an output of "Value not Found"**

3- I don't put a value and it says Please enter a valid input.

Comment: Read the grep man page: grep exits with a non-zero status if the search pattern is not found.

Comment: `if ! grep -w -- "$1" list.txt; then echo 'Not found'; fi`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond This still doesn't help me, doesn't work how I want it.

Comment: @glennjackman I know the exit status but still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
    if grep -w -- "$1" list.txt
    then
        true
    else
        echo "Value not Found"
    fi
else
    echo "Please enter a valid input"
fi
```

Comment: This worked perfectly You got my point and this is what I wanted.

A question: why do we add -- after -w? What does it do because I tried removing it and it doesn't affect anything so what's the point of that

Comment: For example `$1` might be `-v`. You don't want it to be interpreted as an option for `grep`, that's what `--` is good for: it means _end of options._